# Different levels of access to methods

Tags: c#, .net

**Situation:**

I'm creating 2 libraries: X1.dll and X2.dll. They are created and amended separately and their projects couldn't be combined into one solution.

X1.dll contains a definition of the class C1. 
X2.dll contains a definition of the class C2.

X2.dll references X1.dll.

Class C1 has a method M1(). This method is used in the X2.dll and that is the reason why M1() is made as a public method.

I distribute X1.dll and X2.dll to other developers. But I do not want them to call M1() - they can do whatever they want with C1 instances, but do not touch M1(). At the same time, M1() is already public because I have to be able to call it in X2.dll.

**Question:**

What is the best way to organize M1() in order to make it available only for me but still do not merge projects for X1.dll and X2.dll?

There are plenty of awkward solutions like making M1() as M1(string SecreteCode) and hardcode this SecreteCode so I'm the only one who can pass it as the correct argument.

But what is the best practice to achieve this goal?

Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make `M1()` `internal` and add [`InternalsVisibleToAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on your assembly to allow `X2.dll` to call `X1.dll`'s `internal` code. This solution makes *all* `internal` code in `X1` visible in `X2`, but you're sure that no one else is going to call `M1()`.

From the documentation:

> Ordinarily, types and members with internal scope (in C#) and friend
>   scope (in Visual Basic) are visible only in the assembly in which they
>   are defined. The InternalsVisibleToAttribute attribute makes them also
>   visible to the types in a specified assembly, which is known as a
>   friend assembly.

Simply add `[assembly:InternalsVisibleTo("X2")]` to your assembly. If your assembly is signed, you'll need to add the public key of your strong name key like so `[assembly:InternalsVisibleTo("X2, PublicKey=0000000000")]`

This is better than a "secret code" because C# code is easy to decompile and your secret won't be secret for a long time!